# Google Play Services error integrating(Can't register classes)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I have a problem with integrating Google Play Services into my Unity game. I am sure the setup is correctly done on the google play developer console/google play API, and even Unity.
Using ADB Logcat, here is my error log text : https://hastebin.com/varilupaxi.scala (on short, the errors are "Could not register one or more required Java classes." and "InvalidOperationException: There was an error creating a GameServices object.").
Any idea how to fix this ? I also have the latest version of the Google Play Services(0.9.50).
Here it's my Unity C# code : https://hastebin.com/iqajeguvop.cs 
Thanks a lot !
Here are the errors if link doesn't work :

`03-20 10:23:26.173: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.174: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.174: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/common/api/Api: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.174: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/common/api/Api$ApiOptions: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.175: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/common/api/Api$ApiOptions$HasOptions: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.175: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.175: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$Builder: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.175: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/common/api/PendingResult: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.175: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/common/api/Result: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.176: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/common/api/ResultCallback: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.176: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/common/data/DataBufferUtils: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.176: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/Games: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.177: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/Games$GamesOptions: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.177: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/Games$GamesOptions$Builder: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.177: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/Player: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.177: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/PlayerBuffer: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.177: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/PlayerLevel: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.178: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/PlayerLevelInfo: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.178: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/Players: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.178: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/Players$LoadPlayersResult: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.178: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/achievement/Achievement: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.178: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/achievement/Achievements$LoadAchievementsResult: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.179: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/event/Event: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.179: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/event/EventBuffer: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.179: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/event/Events: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.179: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/event/Events$LoadEventsResult: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.179: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/achievement/AchievementBuffer: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.180: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/achievement/Achievements: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.180: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/Leaderboard: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.180: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/LeaderboardBuffer: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.180: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/Leaderboards: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.180: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/LeaderboardScore: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.181: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/LeaderboardScoreBuffer: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.181: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/LeaderboardVariant: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.181: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/Leaderboards$LeaderboardMetadataResult: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.181: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/Leaderboards$LoadScoresResult: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.182: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/Invitation: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.182: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/InvitationBuffer: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.182: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/Invitations: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.182: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/Invitations$LoadInvitationsResult: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.182: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/Multiplayer: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.183: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/Participant: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.183: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/ParticipantResult: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.183: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/LoadMatchesResponse: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.183: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMatch: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.183: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMatchBuffer: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.184: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMatchConfig: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.184: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMatchConfig$Builder: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.184: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMultiplayer: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.184: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMultiplayer$CancelMatchResult: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.184: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMultiplayer$InitiateMatchResult: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.185: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMultiplayer$LeaveMatchResult: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.185: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMultiplayer$LoadMatchesResult: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.185: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMultiplayer$LoadMatchResult: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.185: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMultiplayer$UpdateMatchResult: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.185: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/quest/Quest: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.186: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/quest/QuestBuffer: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.186: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/quest/Quests: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.186: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/quest/Milestone: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.186: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/quest/Quests$LoadQuestsResult: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.186: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/quest/Quests$AcceptQuestResult: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.187: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/quest/Quests$ClaimMilestoneResult: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.187: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/snapshot/Snapshot: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.187: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/snapshot/SnapshotContents: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.187: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/snapshot/SnapshotMetadata: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.187: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/snapshot/SnapshotMetadataBuffer: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.188: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/snapshot/Snapshots: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.188: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/snapshot/Snapshots$CommitSnapshotResult: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.188: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/snapshot/Snapshots$LoadSnapshotsResult: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.188: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/snapshot/Snapshots$OpenSnapshotResult: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.188: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/snapshot/SnapshotMetadataChange: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.189: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/snapshot/SnapshotMetadataChange$Builder: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.189: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/stats/PlayerStats: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.189: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/stats/Stats: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.189: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/stats/Stats$LoadPlayerStatsResult: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.189: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RealTimeMessageReceivedListener: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.189: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RealTimeMultiplayer: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.190: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RealTimeMessage: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.190: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/Room: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.190: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RoomConfig: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.190: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RoomConfig$Builder: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.190: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/nearby/Nearby: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.191: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/nearby/connection/AppIdentifier: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.191: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/nearby/connection/AppMetadata: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.191: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/nearby/connection/Connections: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.191: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/nearby/connection/Connections$StartAdvertisingResult: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.191: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/video/CaptureState: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.192: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/video/VideoCapabilities: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.192: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/video/Videos: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.192: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/video/Videos$CaptureAvailableResult: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.192: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/video/Videos$CaptureCapabilitiesResult: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.192: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/video/Videos$CaptureStateResult: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.193: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/video/Videos$CaptureOverlayStateListener: an exception occurred.
03-20 10:23:26.250: I/Unity(25961): Building GPG services, implicitly attempts silent auth
03-20 10:23:26.250: I/Unity(25961):

03-20 10:23:26.250: I/Unity(25961): (Filename: ./artifacts/generated/common/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)
03-20 10:23:26.253: E/GamesNativeSDK(25961): Could not register one or more required Java classes.
03-20 10:23:26.266: E/Unity(25961): InvalidOperationException: There was an error creating a GameServices object. Check for log errors from GamesNativeSDK
03-20 10:23:26.266: E/Unity(25961):   at GooglePlayGames.Native.PInvoke.GameServicesBuilder.Build (GooglePlayGames.Native.PInvoke.PlatformConfiguration configRef) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
03-20 10:23:26.266: E/Unity(25961):   at GooglePlayGames.Native.NativeClient.InitializeGameServices () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
03-20 10:23:26.266: E/Unity(25961):   at GooglePlayGames.Native.NativeClient.Authenticate (System.Action`2 callback, Boolean silent) [0x00000] in :0 
03-20 10:23:26.266: E/Unity(25961):   at GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform.Authenticate (System.Action`2 callback, Boolean silent) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
03-20 10:23:26.266: E/Unity(25961):   at GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform.Authenticate (System.Action`1 callback, Boolean silent) [0x00000] in :0 
03-20 10:23:26.266: E/Unity(25961):   at GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform.Authenticate (System.Action`1 callback) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
03-20 10:23:26.266: E/Unity(25961):   at GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesLocalUser.Authenticate (System.Action`1 callback) [0x00000] in :0 
03-20 10:23:26.266: E/Unity(25961):   at GooglePlayGame`

Comment: Please don't include context in external links - include it directly in your question.

Comment: I edited, although I think it's a little too much text now

Comment: Maybe you should clear your Plugins folder and try to reimport the Google Play plugin.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming here for a solution, I fixed it by adding to my Proguard File : -keep class com.google.android.gms.**{*;}

Comment: Where is the Proguard like in the project dir?

Comment: Thanks man, I changed the Minify setting in Unity from ProGuard to none, now at least i can build and solve the problem later.

Answer (score 0):

I've been hitting this issue recently (August 2021) after trying to integrate the most recent version of Google Play Games Services into an Android app. I was getting:

```
E/GamesNativeSDK: Can't register class com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/*: an exception occurred.
E/GamesNativeSDK: Can't register class com/google/android/gms/nearby/connection/*: an exception occurred.
E/GamesNativeSDK: Could not register one or more required Java classes.
```

With 25 different classes for the first * (all of which were deprecated earlier by Google and removed in the latest release) and 5 for the second. The latter 5 were fixed by adding:

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:18.0.0'`

to my module's build.gradle dependencies, but for the former 25 I had to downgrade the version of Play Games Services to the last version those 25 classes were still present:

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:20.0.0'`

It looks like a bug in GPGS 21.0.0.